# Replacing items in a list

Tags: haskell, comparative-review

I was wondering why `replace` is not in `base`. I thought, it's because it must be easy to implement with standard combinators. Although I do not like prefix syntax of `Applicative` I wrote it this way:

```
replace a b = map (bool <$> id <*> (const b) <*> (== a))
```

And was slightly surprised after seeing [`replace` in `Data.List.Utils`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/citation-resolve-0.4.2/docs/Data-List-Utils.html#v:replace):

> ```
> replace old new l = join new . split old $ l
> ```

Are there non-opinion based reasons to prefer one than the other in public projects?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not a replacement for `replace` (pun intended).  Its type signature is wrong.  Your code has type `Eq b => b -> b -> [b] -> [b]`, but `replace` should have type `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

`<$>` and `<*>` are infix, not prefix.

I'd prefer this to your implementation:

```
replace' :: Eq b => b -> b -> [b] -> [b]
replace' a b = map (\x -> if (a == x) then b else x)
```

It does the exact same thing in the exact same way, but is simpler and more readable (even a novice Haskell programmer who has never heard of `bool` or `<$>` or `<*>` can read it).  Even more important: it has a type signature.

If you'd decided to cut-and-paste the type signature of the function you wanted to replicate before starting, you would have found out that your version doesn't work as a replacement at compile time -- and if you'd looked at and thought about the type signature, you probably would have wondered why the extra `[]`s were there, and figured it out even earlier.